# how do i get the return value in json after inserting in sql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

i want the return value in json

```
INSERT INTO games (player, score)
VALUES("john", 42) returning *
```

gives me the newly created row, but i want it in json format, so below fails

```
INSERT INTO games (player, score)
VALUES("john", 42) returning json_agg(*)
```

how is it done correctly?

Comment: add more info, the data, what you expect... btw, have you tried to_json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use json_agg using `to_jsonb()`:

```
INSERT INTO games (player, score)
VALUES ('john', 42) 
returning to_jsonb(games);
```

If you are inserting multiple rows and one a **single** large JSON array, you need to wrap this into a CTE:

```
with new_games as (
  insert into games (player, score)
  values ('john', 42), ('peter', 50)
  returning *
)
select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(ng))
from new_games ng;
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you're probably looking for `ROW_TO_JSON()` function :

```
WITH r AS
(
  INSERT INTO games (player, score)
  VALUES('john', 42) 
  RETURNING *
) 
SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(r) 
  FROM r;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ea69826bc50b52204e7475378c581ff4)</kbd>